# Determine range of time where measurements are not NA

Tags: r, timestamp, na

I have a dataset with hundreds of thousands of measurements taken from several subjects. However, the measurements are only partially available, i.e., there may be large stretches with `NA`. I need to establish up front, for which timespan positive data are available for each subject.

Data:

```
df
      timestamp      C     B      A starttime_ms
1  00:00:00.033     NA    NA     NA           33
2  00:00:00.064     NA    NA     NA           64
3  00:00:00.066     NA 0.346     NA           66
4  00:00:00.080 47.876 0.346 22.231           80
5  00:00:00.097 47.876 0.346 22.231           97
6  00:00:00.099 47.876 0.346     NA           99
7  00:00:00.114 47.876 0.346     NA          114
8  00:00:00.130 47.876 0.346     NA          130
9  00:00:00.133     NA 0.346     NA          133
10 00:00:00.147     NA 0.346     NA          147
```

My (humble) solution so far is (i) to pick out the range of `timestamp` values that are not `NA` and to select the first and last such `timestamp` for each subject individually. Here's the code for subject `C`:

```
NotNA_C <- df$timestamp[which(!is.na(df$C))]
range_C <- paste(NotNA_C[1], NotNA_C[length(NotNA_C)], sep = " - ")

range_C
[1] "00:00:00.080" "00:00:00.130"
```

That doesn't look elegant and, what's more, it needs to be repeated for all other subjects. Is there a more efficient way to establish the range of time for which non-`NA` values are available for all subjects in one go?

**EDIT**

I've found a `base R` solution:

```
sapply(df[,2:4], function(x) 
  paste(df$timestamp[which(!is.na(x))][1], 
        df$timestamp[which(!is.na(x))][length(df$timestamp[which(!is.na(x))])], sep = " - "))
                            C                             B                             A 
"00:00:00.080 - 00:00:00.130" "00:00:00.066 - 00:00:00.147" "00:00:00.080 - 00:00:00.097"
```

but would be interested in other solutions as well!

Reproducible data:

```
df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("00:00:00.033", "00:00:00.064", 
                             "00:00:00.066", "00:00:00.080", "00:00:00.097", "00:00:00.099", 
                             "00:00:00.114", "00:00:00.130", "00:00:00.133", "00:00:00.147"
), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 
         NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 
                                0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346), A = c(NA, NA, NA, 22.231, 22.231, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                            NA), starttime_ms = c(33, 64, 66, 80, 97, 99, 114, 130, 133, 
                                                                                  147)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` solution

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- structure(list(timestamp = c("00:00:00.033", "00:00:00.064", 
                                   "00:00:00.066", "00:00:00.080", "00:00:00.097", "00:00:00.099", 
                                   "00:00:00.114", "00:00:00.130", "00:00:00.133", "00:00:00.147"
), C = c(NA, NA, NA, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 47.876, 
         NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 
                        0.346, 0.346, 0.346, 0.346), A = c(NA, NA, NA, 22.231, 22.231, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                           NA), starttime_ms = c(33, 64, 66, 80, 97, 99, 114, 130, 133, 
                                                                                 147)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(timestamp, starttime_ms)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%  
  drop_na() %>% 
  summarise(min = timestamp %>% min(),
            max = timestamp %>% max())
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   name  min          max         
#>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 A     00:00:00.080 00:00:00.097
#> 2 B     00:00:00.066 00:00:00.147
#> 3 C     00:00:00.080 00:00:00.130
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the `cumsum` of `diff`erences where there's no NA, coerce them to logical and subset first and last element.

```
lapply(data.frame(apply(rbind(0, diff(!sapply(df[c("C", "B", "A")], is.na))), 2, cumsum)),
       function(x) c(df$timestamp[as.logical(x)][1], rev(df$timestamp[as.logical(x)])[1]))
# $C
# [1] "00:00:00.080" "00:00:00.130"
# 
# $B
# [1] "00:00:00.066" "00:00:00.147"
# 
# $A
# [1] "00:00:00.080" "00:00:00.097"
```